# How can I get a value from another Python file?

Tags: python

I have two classes, the first is in main.py, and the second is in display_item.py.

main.py

```
def selectedCell(self):
    global cell_id
    empty_list = []
    for i in range(0, 6):
        empty_list.append(qTableFor.item(qTableFor.currentRow(), i).text())

    cell_id = empty_list[0]
    return cell_id
```

I want to send the `cell_id` value to display_item.py.
However, I could not find a way to do that even I have searched a lot.

I have imported `cell_id` like this in display_item.py:

```
from Restarted_PyQt5.I_Added_More.Product_Management_App.main import cell_id
```

And then

```
def get_cell_id(self):
    print("cell id from other py", cell_id)
```

But it prints "None". I could not get the value that I want to have.

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't shown enough details of your code for us to be able to tell you why this is not working as intended. Please see why and how to create a [mre].

Comment: first of those are not classes but files, second, to get that value changed to sth else you need to call that function (otherwise it should default to some value you have specified otherwise or throw an error)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the global keyword inside the function you cannot access the value of a variable that you assign in function with global keyword until you call the function.

For example

I create a function one

```
def one():
    global val1
    val1=100
```

Call the function

`one()`

now I print the value1

`print(val1)`

The output will be 100

Now, When I create another function scnd()

```
def scnd():
    global val2
    val2=500
```

Now, I'll print the value of val2 but I get an error

`NameError: name 'val2' is not defined`

So, you have to call the function at least one time in order to access the variable

[Example Code](https://onecompiler.com/python/3x7uen5r3)